# How to display foreign key related data in razor view in MVC using Ado.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ado.net

here is my class

```
 public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public Dept Dept { get; set; }
}
```

For showing list i use ado.net. here is my controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo();
        List<Student> students = repo.GetStudent().ToList();
        return View(students);
    }
```

GetStudent method

```
public List<Student> GetStudent()
    {
        connection();
        List<Student> stdList = new List<Student>();


        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetStudent", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Dept dpt = new Dept();


            dpt.DeptId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DeptId"]);// here found student Id 
            dpt.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);// here found student name 


            stdList.Add(
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentId"]),
                    Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),
                    Roll = Convert.ToString(dr["Roll"]),
                    DeptId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DeptId"]),
                    Dept = dpt
                }
                );


        }

        return stdList;
    }
```

and the razor view is:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Roll)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dept.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Store Procedure:

```
select StudentTbl.StudentId,StudentTbl.Name,StudentTbl.ROll, StudentTbl.DeptId,DeptTbl.Name
from  Demo.dbo.StudentTbl inner join 
Demo.dbo.DeptTbl ON  StudentTbl.DeptId = DeptTbl.DeptId
```

Currently it shows department Id.
Now the problem is in the list i don't know how to show department name. 
How can i achieve that ? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Now when i bind Dept data in dpt object it find StudentTbl Id & Name

Comment: in your query, INNER JOIN to the department table (via Dept ID of course) to allow you to get the department data for each student. And then when you populate your Student class, set its Dept object's properties with the values from the appropriate columns. You haven't shown us how you convert from the DataTable to a list of "Student" objects, but presumably you have some code for that. Or have you just made the DataTable your model directly (in which case you can just reference the columns directly from the view)? If so, then what's the point of the Student class? It's not clear.

Comment: Can you please check this now . I try to follow your instruction but can not success. What's wrong with this code

Comment: what part goes wrong, precisely? Do you get an error, or something else is wrong? Please clarify. The code you've shown is ok apart from `dpt.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);` obviously needs to be changed to get the Department name. Problem is, I can't see your stored procedure code, so I don't know what you did in there or what you called the department name column in the output, so I can't advise you easily. Please show that code if you need further help

Comment: Dept table Name is define as Name also..so i write `dpt.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]);`. I give my store procedure. Can you please give me advise?

Comment: First try simply `dr["DeptTbl.Name"]`, that might work, I'm not sure though. If not, then the normal thing is to use aliases for your column names, to make them unique: `select StudentTbl.StudentId,StudentTbl.Name as StudentName ,StudentTbl.ROll, StudentTbl.DeptId,DeptTbl.Name as DeptName` and then of course change your C# code to match the new aliases

Comment: Aliases name works perfectly .Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great. I have added that as the answer, for future readers. Please consider marking it as "accepted", since it helped you - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution to this is to use aliases for your column names, to make them unique:

```
select 
  StudentTbl.StudentId,
  StudentTbl.Name as StudentName,
  StudentTbl.ROll, 
  StudentTbl.DeptId,DeptTbl.Name as DeptName
```

and then of course change your C# code to match the new aliases:

```
dpt.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["DeptName"]);
```

and

```
Name = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentName"])
```